# Is it possible to have durative actions in Erlang?

Tags: function, timer, erlang

I would like to execute a function for a specific interval of time, I mean:

```
action()->
...
...
move(2) for 3 sec. %hypothetical example  where it's executed each sec.
```

I thought that I could do this:

```
action() -> 
... 
... 
move(2),
sleep(1),
move(2),
sleep(1),
move(2).
```

But, I wonder if there's another way to implement it, because I looked into the timer module but I didn't find anything that I could use.

Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer like a 1000 times, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is what you're looking for

To answer your question quickly:

```
action(0)->
    done;
action(Count)->
    io:format("moved"),
    sleep(1000),
    action(Count - 1).
```

To make something useful:

```
   action()->
        Pid = spawn(fun()->start_moving(3) end),
        sleep(10),
        exit(Pid, terminate).
    start_moving(0)->
        done;
    start_moving(Count)->
        io:format("moved a little"),
        sleep(1000),
        start_moving(Count -1).
```

You need to evolve this according to your application, here is an example where you have good control over your interval task:

```
action()->
    Ref = make_ref(),
    Count = 3,
    Interval = 1000,
    Pid = spawn(fun()->start_moving(Ref, Count, Interval) end),
    %do lots of stuff
    sleep(10000)
    % stop moving
    Pid ! {Ref, stop}.

start_moving(Ref, Interval, 0)->
    done;
start_moving(Ref, Interval, Count)->
    receive
        {Ref, stop}->
             ok;
        _->
             start_moving(Ref, Interval, Count)
    after
        Interval->
            io:format("moving"),
            start_moving(Ref, Interval, Count - 1)
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

If instead of sleeping, you just want to keep calling the function until the time elapses, you could use something like this:

```
execute_while(Fun, N)->
  execute_while(Fun, N, timer:tc(Fun)).

execute_while(Fun, N, {Time, _Value}) when N>=Time ->
  {Time2, Value2} = timer:tc(Fun),
  execute_while(Fun, N, {Time + Time2, Value2});
execute_while(_, _, R) ->
R.
```

Call it like so:

```
execute_while(fun()-> move() end, 1000).
```